# grep backslash in negative lookbehind

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to find the number of occurrences of `XXX` in my latex document that are not in the form of a command as `\XXX`. Therefore I am looking for occurrences that are not preceded by a backslash.

I tried the following:

```
grep -c -e '(?<!\)XXX' test.tex    #result: grep: Unmatched ) or \)
grep -c -e '(?<!\\)XXX' test.tex   #result: 0
grep -c -e "(?<!\\)XXX" test.tex   #result: -bash: !\\: event not found
```

none of them work as intended. In fact I don't understand the last error message at all.

My test.tex contains only the following lines

```
%test.tex

XXX

\XXX
```

So the expected result is `1`.

Any ideas?

Ps.: I am working in bash.

Comment: FYI, in your last example, the ! in double quotes is interpreted as a history expansion, but '!\\' is not a valid history expansion expression.

Answer (score 62):

Neither standard nor extended regular expressions support the look behind. Use Perl compatible regexes:

```
grep -P '(?<!\\)xxx' test.tex
```

Comment: this seems to work, except I did a cross check where I searched for `XXX` for `\\XXX` and for `(?<!\\)XXX`. The first gave 39, the second 10 and the last one 34. Those numbers don't add up, so something isn't working as I expected. But this may go beyond my initial question.

Comment: @Simon: Maybe there are several occurrences on the same line?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
grep -P '(?<!\\)\bXXX\b' test.tex
```

Comment: this helps, but according to my man page for grep, -P is "highly experimental", is this still true? is there a non-pearl way to do lookbehinds and lookaheads with grep?

Comment: @santiagoarizti: `grep -P` is here for very long time and I never heard it should be consider "experimental". Since I like Perl regular expression functionality, I always go with this switch and use Perl format.

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` version on my MacOS Catalina does not even have the `-P` flag for Perl style regex,

```
    $ grep --version
    grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

So I just rolled my own version of the `grep -l` command which I needed to get list of files that matched a negative lookahead regex, below is the source code, feel free to adapt to your own needs,

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
      
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    
    # Tries to mimic at least partially `grep -l` command, and provides support for look-arounds using Perl regex'
    # Usage: ls <some folder> | grepList.pl <reg-ex>
    # Algorithm:
    # Open each file in the list supplied
    #   Apply regex to each line, as soon as it matches output file name to STDOUT and continue to next file
    #   If EOF file reached, means file did not match, do not print file name, and move on to next file
    # Runtime complexity: O(m * n), where m is number of files and n is the maximum number of lines a file can have
    # Space complexity:   O(1), no intermediary memory storage needed
    
    my $reg_ex = qr/$ARGV[0]/;
    
    while(<STDIN>) {
        chop($_);
        my $file = $_;
        open(IN, $file) || die "Unable to open $file: $!";
        while(<IN>) {
            my $line = $_;
            if ($line =~ /$reg_ex/) {
                print "$file\n";
                last;
            }
        }
    }
```